# Make Hidden Fields Not Required

Tags: javascript

***Please No jquery Solutions***

Hello Everyone. I have searched all the forums but can't find the answers I am looking for as I have found similar problems, but they all seem to be resolved through jquery. I do not want to use jquery for this.

I am trying to make hidden fields not required for a form I am using for my website. How can the fields be required to input information when they are showing, but not required when they are hidden? Below is the code I am using which seems to be common on the internet:

I am also using Contact Form 7 on WordPress to implement this code, and build my form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function HidePart(d) {document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";}
function ShowPart(d) {document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";}
function CheckboxChecked(b,d) {
if(b) {ShowPart(d);}
else {HidePart(d);}
}
</script>


<p><input type="checkbox" name="Form1" value="yes" onclick="CheckboxChecked(this.checked,'checkboxdiv1')">More Info</p>


<!-- Form 1 -->

<div id="checkboxdiv1" style="display:none">
<p> Username: <input type="text" name="Usrname" required></p>
<p> FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName" required></p>
<p> LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" required></p>
<p> MothersName: <input type="text" name="MothersName" required></p>
<p> FathersName: <input type="text" name="FathersName" required></p>
<p> SiblingsName: <input type="text" name="SiblingsName" required></p>
</div>


<!-- Form 2 -->

<p><input type="checkbox" name="Form2" value="yes" onclick="CheckboxChecked(this.checked,'checkboxdiv2')">More Info</p>


<div id="checkboxdiv2" style="display:none">
<p> Username2: <input type="text" name="usrname2" required></p>
<p> FirstName2: <input type="text" name="FirstName2" required></p>
<p> LastName2: <input type="text" name="LastName2" required></p>
<p> MothersName2: <input type="text" name="MothersName2" required></p>
<p> FathersName2: <input type="text" name="FathersName2" required></p>
<p> SiblingsName2: <input type="text" name="SiblingsName2" required></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe also remove the `required` attribute as well?

Comment: I could do that, but if there is a solution for the end user to validate there form that would be great too!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function HidePart(d) {
   var x =document.getElementById(d);
   x.style.display = "none";
   x.setAttribute ("required", "false");
}
```

And, of course, the reverse when showing a section.

Comment: Darn, this looks like it should work, but it's not in the Contact Form 7 plugin for WordPress. Is there any special place I should place this function?

Comment: I've just modified `HidePart` by saving the result of `document.getElementById` in a variable, then added the `setAttribute` to it.  So, put it where your `HidePart` and `ShowPart` functions already are.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding required = "true" by  javascript on show and remove on hide?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your comment?